# problem to show a div with position absolute with parents in a scrollable sidebar

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble showing a div with position absolute with parents in a scrollable sidebar

i have this structure on my sidebar:

```
<sidebar>
<scrollable menu items>
<ul>
<li>
<a />
<drop dowm div/>
</li>
</ul>
</scrollable menu items>
</sidebar>
```

but I can't show my div (dropdown item) with position absolute on the screen:

[image]

my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
  height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.main{
  display: flex;
}
.header{
  height: 65px;
  background: #3c8dbc;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content{
  height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
}
.test{
  overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}

.scrollside{
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    overflow: auto !important;
}
.sidebar{
    max-width: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #009688;
    background: #3c8dbc;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.menu-ul{
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    -webkit-text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
        margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu-li{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
.menu-a{
  padding: 12px;
}
.dropdown{
  display: block;
    height: 400px !important;
    width: 400px !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 1500;
    background: #307096;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
header
</div>
<div class="main">
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="scrollside">
  <ul class="menu-ul">
  <li class="menu-li">
     <a class="menu-a">DropDown</a>
     <div class="dropdown">
     aaaaa
     </div>
  </li>
    <li class="menu-li">
     <a class="menu-a">DropDown 2</a>
     <div class="dropdown">
     aaaaa
     </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class"content">
<div class="test">
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
        <li>UFEHAUFAHUHAFEUFA</li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I know the problem is in my parent's divs, but I don't know how to solve it because I need this sidebar menu with scroll

Comment: First make sure you fix the typo `class"content"` to `class="content"`, then apply `overflow:auto` on `.content` class.

Comment: @ismi i try and not sucess: https://jsfiddle.net/yeuzvpqa/2/

Comment: You want to scroll the sidebar or the content ?

Comment: my sidebar and my content,
my sidebar is already scrolling the problem is that I can't make my div dropdown with position absolute appear on the screen.

Comment: i want show my class: dropdown

Comment: If you want to show the dropdown class contents then you need to update the left value from`.dropdown` class `left: 100%`. https://jsfiddle.net/21nmrshL/

Comment: If you want to hide and show the sidebar based on your each nav item click then follow this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/rz596b8f/

Comment: I need the dropdown to be next to >> the sidebar